# Implementing a method in the linkedList that returns the current node

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm implementing a generic linkedList, but I had a hard time writing a function that returns the current node. It always returns the last added node. I'm sharing my code below.

I have searched for similar questions but I didn't find what I want.

Here's the linkedList file. I'm sure the add method which is vorne() is working as expected. It adds elements at the beginning.

```
public class Liste<T> {

    // Points to the head of the Linked List
    // i.e the first element
    Node<T> head;
    Node<T> tail;

    static int size = 0;
    

    static class Node<T> {
        // Data Stored in each Node of the Linked List
        T data;

        // Pointer to the next node in the Linked List
        Node<T> next;
        // Node class constructor used to initializes the data
        // in each Node
        private Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public static <T> Liste<T> neu() {
        Liste<T> l = new Liste<T>();
        return l;
    }

    public static <T> Liste<T> einfuegen(Liste o, T auD, Nat nat) {

        return null;
    }
    // Add element at the beginning
    public static <T> Liste<T> vorne(Liste<T> list, T data) {
        
        //Create new node  
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        
        //Checks if the list is empty.  
        if(list.head == null) {  
             //If list is empty, both head and tail would point to new node.  
            list.head = newNode;  
            list.tail = newNode;  
            newNode.next = list.head; 
            size++;
        }  
        else {  
            //Store data into temporary node  
            Node temp = list.head;  
            //New node will point to temp as next node  
            newNode.next = temp;  
            //New node will be the head node  
            list.head = newNode;  
            //Since, it is circular linked list tail will point to head.  
            list.tail.next = list.head;  
            size++;
        }  
        
        
        return list;
    }
    
    // This method should return the last added element
    public static <T> T kopf(Liste<T> lNat) {
        // Throws an Exception if the List is empty 
        if (lNat.head == null) { 
            System.out.print("No Element found");
        } 
  
        return lNat.head.data;
    }
    // This method should return all the elements except the first element.
    public static <T> Liste<T> rest(Liste<T> lString) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        if (lString.head != null) {
            lString.head = lString.head.next;
            }
        
        return lString;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return size;
    }
    

    

}
```

The problem arises here!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Liste<String> l0 = Liste.neu();
        Liste<String> l1a = Liste.vorne(l0, "AuD");
        Liste<String> l1b = Liste.vorne(l0, "PFP");
        Liste<String> l2a = Liste.vorne(l1a, "FAUL");
        Liste<String> l2b = Liste.vorne(l1b, "FAIL");
        
        //Liste<String> l1x = Liste.rest(l2b);
        //Liste<String> l1y = Liste.rest(l2b);
        //Liste<String> l0x = Liste.rest(l1x);
        //Liste<String> l0y = Liste.rest(l1y);
        //String l0y = Liste.kopf(l2a);
        
        System.out.println(l1b.getCount());
        System.out.println(Liste.kopf(l2a));

    

    }
```

The output:

```
4
FAIL
```

when I call the kopf method which supposes to return the last added element, it returns the string "FAIL" instead of "FAUL". I have stored it in a separate object, and I am calling l2a object, so why it's returning "FAIL". As you can see, I'm creating a new list using neu() method, then I'm using the same list to add elements. I think it's a silly bug that I don't see.
It seems I can't figure it out. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is almost all the code `static`? That makes it very hard to reason about anything here. And you returning a list AND modifying the passed in list and storing the returned list a variable of a new name makes it even harder.

Comment: `Liste#vorne` returns the same reference as you pass into the method. Consequently, all your variables (`l0, lxy`) share a reference to the **same list**. So it is no wonder, that the count is 4 as you added 4 elements to the only existing list. And of course the last element you added to the front of the list was *FAIL* as your `List#kopf` confirms.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I'm using static because the assignment requires me to use static. I think the problem is that the lines in the main method are being called all of them. But how it returns "FAIL" if I'm calling the method kopf from the l2a object.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the response! My objective is to make the function kopf to returns the element that l2a added which is the String "FAUL". If I don't link them to the same reference, then each element will be in a separate list, right?

Comment: Can you give me a hint on where to modify the code?

Comment: Observe closely, how the list goes in and out of the method `vorne`. It is the same list as you don't create a new one, right? The only thing the method does is adding an element to it in the front and then returns the same list you passed to it. In `main` you just store the returned reference (to the same list) in a new variable.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to return the elements of the linkedList except the first element. You can see I have implemented the rest() method but it's not giving the expected result

Comment: If I separated them inside the vorne, then each element will have its own list.